# Fourier transform to solve $\int_{- \infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^3(x)}{x^3}\,dx$

Tags: fourier-transform

I think that I am almost there:

giving $P(x)=1$ for $x \in ]-1/2;1/2[$ and $P(x)=0$ elsewhere.

I managed to find that the convolution product $P*P*P=\frac{3}{4}-x^2$ for $x \in [-1/2;1/2]$

I found that Reverse Fourier transform of $P$ is $p=\frac{1}{2\pi}\times \frac{\sin(x/2)}{x/2}$

knowing that Fourier Transform of 
$p\times p \times p$ is $\frac{1}{4\pi^2}P*P*P$

We then get :

$\int_{- \infty}^{+\infty} p(x)\times p(x) \times p(x)\times e^{ikx}dx =\frac{1}{4\pi^2}P*P*P(k)$

$\int_{- \infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{8\pi^3} \frac{\sin^3(x)}{x^3}\times e^{ikx}dx =\frac{1}{4\pi^2}P*P*P(k)$

Then for $k=0$, $\int_{- \infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{8\pi^3} \frac{\sin^3(x)}{x^3}dx =\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\frac{3}{4}$

then I find $\int_{- \infty}^{+\infty}  \frac{\sin^3(x)}{x^3}\,dx =\frac{3\pi}{2}$

but this is wrong because $\int_{- \infty}^{+\infty}  \frac{\sin^3(x)}{x^3}\,dx =\frac{3\pi}{4}$

Where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: By the way, if you'd like an alternative to Fourier analysis, you can make a double integral using $x^{-3}=\frac12 \int_0^\infty y^2\exp (-xy)dy$. The result $\sin x=\frac{\exp ix-\exp -ix}{2i}$ lets you integrate out $x$, leaving a $y$-integral of a rational function of $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is you forgot $p=\operatorname{sinc}\frac{x}{2}\not\equiv\operatorname{sinc}x$. (In case the notation is unfamiliar, $\operatorname{sinc}x=\frac{\sin x}{x}$, with $\operatorname{sinc}0=1$ for continuity.) We have $\int_{\Bbb R}\operatorname{sinc}^3\frac{x}{2} dx=2\int_{\Bbb R}\operatorname{sinc}^3y dy$ by a trivial substitution.

Comment: Thanks JG I now understand my mistake. All is clear.